# store is not updating in redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, redux-toolkit

So I have a very simple redux app using redux toolkit implementation in nextjs. I want to save the user Id of any user selected from the antd table, in the store. Then access the id from other components. My code is like so...

**_app.js**

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'w3-css/w3.css'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
import '../styles/Typeahead.css'
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {store} from "../redux/store";

export default function MyApp({
    Component,
    pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {

    return (
        <div>
            <SessionProvider session={session}>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Provider>
            </SessionProvider>
        </div>

    )
}
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { devToolsEnhancer } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import ActiveUserReducer from '../redux/features/ActiveUser/ActiveUserSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        activeUser: ActiveUserReducer
    },
    devToolsEnhancer
})
```

**ActiveUserSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice, current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {

    value: 0,
}

export const ActiveUserSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'ActiveUser',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        replace: (state, action) => {
            state.value = action.payload
            // console.log('this is the current state', current(state))
        }
    }
})

export const { replace } = ActiveUserSlice.actions

export default ActiveUserSlice.reducer
```

**UserList.js**

```
import { useState, useContext }from 'react'
import { Table, Radio, Divider } from 'antd'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {replace} from "../../redux/features/ActiveUser/ActivePatientSlice";


export default function UserList() {

    const [selectionType, setSelectionType] = useState('radio')
    const userId = useSelector((state) => state.activeUser.value)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const columns = [
        {
          title: 'Name',
          dataIndex: 'name',
          render: (text) => <a>{text}</a>,
        },
        {
          title: 'Age',
          dataIndex: 'age',
        },
        {
          title: 'Address',
          dataIndex: 'address',
        },
      ];
      const data = [
        {
          key: '1',
          name: 'John Brown',
          age: 32,
          address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
        },
        {
          key: '2',
          name: 'Jim Green',
          age: 42,
          address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
        },
        {
          key: '3',
          name: 'Joe Black',
          age: 32,
          address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
        },
        {
          key: '4',
          name: 'Disabled User',
          age: 99,
          address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
        },
      ];
    const rowSelection = {
        onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
            const idValue = selectedRows[0].key
            dispatch(replace(idValue))
        }
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <Radio.Group
                onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                    setSelectionType(value);
                }}
                value={selectionType}
            >
                <Radio value="checkbox">Select many</Radio>
                <Radio value="radio">Select one</Radio>
            </Radio.Group>

            <Divider />
            <Table
                rowSelection={{
                    type: selectionType,
                    ...rowSelection,
                }}
                columns={columns}
                dataSource={data}
                rowKey={`key`}
            />

            <h1>{userId}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

// User display component
**UserDisplay.js**

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { replace } from '../redux/features/ActiveUser/ActiveUserSlice'
import { store } from '../redux/store'

export default function UserDisplay() {
    const userId = useSelector((state) => state.activeUser.value)

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{userId}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

// User select page
**UserSelectPage.js**

```
import UserList from "../../components/UserList";

export default function UserSelectPage() {

    return(
        <div>
            <UserList />
        </div>
    )
}
```

// User Id display page

**UserDisplayPage.js**

```
import UserDisplay from "../components/UserDisplay";

export default function Display() {
    return(
        <div>
            <UserDisplay />
        </div>
    )
}
```

The problem is that when I select a new user from the table in 'UserList' component, the dispatch function attached to the onchange event seems to fire because the {userId} displayed in the component's jsx updates, but the {userId} displayed in the 'UserDisplay' component keeps returning only the initialState.

Please tell me what am i doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like it's probably a issue with the Next.js + Redux implementation.  Your user page is getting built with the initial state.  But I don't know enough to answer this properly.

Comment: I figure as well. Thanks for comment though.